# Plotting envfit vectors (vegan package) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I am working on finalizing a NMDS plot that I created in vegan and ggplot2 but cannot figure out how to add envfit species-loading vectors to the plot. When I try to it says "invalid graphics state".

The example below is slightly modified from another question ([Plotting ordiellipse function from vegan package onto NMDS plot created in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794419/plotting-ordiellipse-function-from-vegan-package-onto-nmds-plot-created-in-ggplo)) but it expressed exactly the example I wanted to include since I used this question to help me get metaMDS into ggplot2 in the first place:

```
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
data(dune)

# calculate distance for NMDS
NMDS.log<-log(dune+1)
sol <- metaMDS(NMDS.log)

# Create meta data for grouping
MyMeta = data.frame(
  sites = c(2,13,4,16,6,1,8,5,17,15,10,11,9,18,3,20,14,19,12,7),
  amt = c("hi", "hi", "hi", "md", "lo", "hi", "hi", "lo", "md", "md", "lo", 
      "lo", "hi", "lo", "hi", "md", "md", "lo", "hi", "lo"),
row.names = "sites")

# plot NMDS using basic plot function and color points by "amt" from MyMeta
plot(sol$points, col = MyMeta$amt)

# same in ggplot2
NMDS = data.frame(MDS1 = sol$points[,1], MDS2 = sol$points[,2])
ggplot(data = NMDS, aes(MDS1, MDS2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(data = MyMeta, color = MyMeta$amt))

#Add species loadings
vec.sp<-envfit(sol$points, NMDS.log, perm=1000)
plot(vec.sp, p.max=0.1, col="blue")
```

Comment: +1 Excellent question. Do study my Answer to see how one should go about extracting scores from objects or plotting them. You shouldn't, in most instances with **vegan** need to do things like `sol$points` as we provide `scores()` methods for this as well as a `plot()` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start with adding libraries. Additionally library `grid` is necessary.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(vegan)
library(grid)
data(dune)
```

Do metaMDS analysis and save results in data frame.

```
NMDS.log<-log(dune+1)
sol <- metaMDS(NMDS.log)

NMDS = data.frame(MDS1 = sol$points[,1], MDS2 = sol$points[,2])
```

Add species loadings and save them as data frame. Directions of arrows cosines are stored in list `vectors` and matrix `arrows`. To get coordinates of the arrows those direction values should be multiplied by square root of `r2` values that are stored in `vectors$r`. More straight forward way is to use function `scores()` as provided in answer of @Gavin Simpson. Then add new column containing `species` names.

```
vec.sp<-envfit(sol$points, NMDS.log, perm=1000)
vec.sp.df<-as.data.frame(vec.sp$vectors$arrows*sqrt(vec.sp$vectors$r))
vec.sp.df$species<-rownames(vec.sp.df)
```

Arrows are added with `geom_segment()` and species names with `geom_text()`. For both tasks data frame `vec.sp.df` is used.

```
ggplot(data = NMDS, aes(MDS1, MDS2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(data = MyMeta, color = MyMeta$amt))+
  geom_segment(data=vec.sp.df,aes(x=0,xend=MDS1,y=0,yend=MDS2),
      arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")),colour="grey",inherit_aes=FALSE) + 
  geom_text(data=vec.sp.df,aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,label=species),size=5)+
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great! With a little manipulation I was able to make it look really nice and strangely the loadings seem to be more accurate than the ones from envfit were. I think those may have shown the p-value through the length of the line but I would rather report that myself. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hmm, something seems off here - the lengths of the vectors *shouldn't* be the same... They aren't in the output from `envfit`. And @HFBrowning the length of the vector simply indicates the strength of the correlation; it is not a direct indication of the *p* value.

Comment: Ahh, and I see now - you shouldn't delve into objects and rip out components. Use the accessor functions - in this case `scores(vec.sp, display = "vectors")`. See my Answer for a fully worked through example.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this isn't the way it should be. I'll delete my answer as soon as @HFBrowning will accept yours.

Comment: @DidzisElferts Rather than delete it, perhaps just update it? I mean you did most of the hard work which I just copied for my Answer, only modifying a few bits for style and to extract the same data that the `plot.envfit` methods uses.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Updated my answer - solution without function scores() :)

Answer (score 16):

The problem with the (otherwise excellent) accepted answer, and which explains why the vectors are all of the same length in the included figure [*Note that the accepted Answer has now been edited to scale the arrows in the manner I describe below, to avoid confusion for users coming across the Q&A*], is that what is stored in the `$vectors$arrows` component of the object returned by `envfit()` are the direction cosines of the fitted vectors. These are all of unit length, and hence the arrows in @Didzis Elferts' plot are all the same length. This is different to the output from `plot(envfit(sol, NMDS.log))`, and arises because we scale the vector arrow coordinates by the correlation with the ordination configuration ("axes"). That way, species that show a weak relationship with the ordination configuration get shorter arrows. The scaling is done by multiplying the direction cosines by `sqrt(r2)` where `r2` are the values shown in the table of printed output. When *adding* the vectors to an existing plot, **vegan** also tries to scale the set of vectors such that they fill the available plot space whilst maintaining the relative lengths of the arrows. How this is done is discussed in the **Details** section of `?envfit` and requires the use of the un-exported function `vegan:::ordiArrowMul(result_of_envfit)`.

Here is a full working example that replicates the behaviour of `plot.envfit` using **ggplot2**:

```
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
data(dune)

# calculate distance for NMDS
NMDS.log<-log1p(dune)
set.seed(42)
sol <- metaMDS(NMDS.log)

scrs <- as.data.frame(scores(sol, display = "sites"))
scrs <- cbind(scrs, Group = c("hi","hi","hi","md","lo","hi","hi","lo","md","md",
                              "lo","lo","hi","lo","hi","md","md","lo","hi","lo"))

set.seed(123)
vf <- envfit(sol, NMDS.log, perm = 999)
```

If we stop at this point and look at `vf`:

```
> vf

***VECTORS

             NMDS1       NMDS2     r2 Pr(>r)    
Belper -0.78061195 -0.62501598 0.1942  0.174    
Empnig -0.01315693  0.99991344 0.2501  0.054 .  
Junbuf  0.22941001 -0.97332987 0.1397  0.293    
Junart  0.99999981 -0.00062172 0.3647  0.022 *  
Airpra -0.20995196  0.97771170 0.5376  0.002 ** 
Elepal  0.98959723  0.14386566 0.6634  0.001 ***
Rumace -0.87985767 -0.47523728 0.0948  0.429
.... <truncated>
```

So the `r2` data is used to scale the values in columns `NMDS1` and `NMDS2`. The final plot is produced with:

```
spp.scrs <- as.data.frame(scores(vf, display = "vectors"))
spp.scrs <- cbind(spp.scrs, Species = rownames(spp.scrs))

p <- ggplot(scrs) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, colour = Group)) +
  coord_fixed() + ## need aspect ratio of 1!
  geom_segment(data = spp.scrs,
               aes(x = 0, xend = NMDS1, y = 0, yend = NMDS2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, "cm")), colour = "grey") +
  geom_text(data = spp.scrs, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, label = Species),
            size = 3)
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: As long as coord_fixed() is kept at ratio=1, will the point locations in a ggplot always match the (correct) point locations of a Vegan ordiplot?

Comment: @Vinterwoo With or without the `coord_fixed` & `ratio = 1` the points will match the correct point locations  in the `plot` method for `envfit`. The `coord_fixed` et al parts are required to maintain the metric properties of the ordination solutions; both axes should be scaled in the same "units".

Comment: Thanks for that Gavin. In regards to using envfit vectors to overlay information about how species effect site ordination location - It was my (most likely flawed) understanding that this kind of info could not be pulled out of a NMDS analysis. And that it was impossible to get info on the variance explained by ordination plots.  It seems the significance codes from envfit, and the location of the arrows in spp.scores seem to give this kind of info. My apologies if this comment address the more global aspects of the original question, and not the specifics of your excellent answer.

Comment: Your understanding is only relevant if the NMDS doesn't have access to the species data. NMDS itself doesn't use this info; that is embedded in the dissimilarity matrix (Dij) and NMDS uses that. However, we can project vectors or points into the NMDS solution using ideas familiar from other methods. `metaMDS`'s `plot` method can add species points as weighted averages of the NMDS site scores if you fit the model using the raw data not the Dij. `envfit` uses the well-established method of vector fitting, *post hoc*.

Comment: @Vinterwoo The main thing to note though is that these so-derived scores (whichever way you do it) are somewhat removed from the "species" info embedded in the NMDS solution. That itself depends on the dissimilarity coefficient used.

Comment: @Vinterwoo You might also be interested in this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735864/429846)

Comment: When I do this, my plot's scale is changed. It seems to be because `Species` are wanting to push the axis boundaries which just shrinks my actual plot. Any idea how to stop this?
https://imgur.com/a/pIjnwBC

Comment: @Lamma perhaps you need to multiply by the factor obtained with vegan:::ordiArrowMul(result_of_envfit).

Comment: @GavinSimpson is there a reason why you did not multiply by the factor obtained by vegan:::ordiArrowMul(result_of_envfit) in your answer? This was mentioned but not implemented (as shown by the answer by crazysantaclaus)? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

May i add something late?

Envfit provides pvalues, and sometimes you want to just plot the significant parameters (something vegan can do for you with p.=0.05 in the plot command). I struggled to do that with ggplot2. Here is my solution, maybe you find a more elegant one?

Starting from Didzis' answer from above:

```
ef<-envfit(sol$points, NMDS.log, perm=1000)
ef.df<-as.data.frame(ef$vectors$arrows*sqrt(ef$vectors$r))
ef.df$species<-rownames(ef.df)

#only significant pvalues
#shortcutting ef$vectors
A <- as.list(ef$vectors)
#creating the dataframe
pvals<-as.data.frame(A$pvals)
arrows<-as.data.frame(A$arrows*sqrt(A$r))
C<-cbind(arrows, pvals)
#subset
Cred<-subset(C,pvals<0.05)
Cred <- cbind(Cred, Species = rownames(Cred))
```

"Cred "can now be implemented in the geom_segment-argument as discussed above.

Answer (score 3):

Short addition: To get a full representation of the `plot.envfit` functionality within `ggplot2` aka "arrow lengths make full use of plot area" a factor needs to be applied. I don't know if it was intentionally left out in the answers above, as it was even specifically mentioned by Gavin? Just extract the required scaling factor using `arrow_factor <- ordiArrowMul(vf)` and then you can either apply it to both NMDS columns in `spp.scrs` or you can do this manually like

```r
arrow_factor <- ordiArrowMul(vf)
spp.scrs <- as.data.frame(scores(vf, display = "vectors")) * arrow_factor
spp.scrs <- cbind(spp.scrs, Species = rownames(spp.scrs), Pvalues = vf$vectors$pvals, R_squared = vf$vectors$r)

# select significance similarly to `plot(vf, p.max = 0.01)`
spp.scrs <- subset(spp.scrs, Pvalues < 0.01)

# you can also add the arrow factor in here (don't do both!)
ggplot(scrs) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, colour = Group)) +
  coord_fixed() + ## need aspect ratio of 1!
  geom_segment(data = spp.scrs,
               aes(x = 0, xend = NMDS1 * arrow_factor, y = 0, yend = NMDS2 * arrow_factor),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, "cm")), colour = "grey") +
  geom_text(data = spp.scrs, aes(x = NMDS1 * arrow_factor, y = NMDS2 * arrow_factor, label = Species),
            size = 3)
```