# Including arrows in NMDS plot in R vegan package

Tags: r, vegan

I'm using the vegan package to plot a NMDS in R analyzing community similarities.
This is based on a community matrix that includes different treatments:

```
NMDS=metaMDS(community_matrix,k=2,trymax=100)
plot(NMDS)
```

Could anybody tell me how to I can draw arrows to show how individual species respond to treatments?

Answer (score 5):

Arrows would be the wrong interpretation in such a plot; there is no reason whatsoever to assume that in a plot best preserving rank-order dissimilarity of samples the species respond linearly in that space.

We add species as they would be in a CA, as a weighted average of the sample scores, possibly expanded.

You can add species vectors by projecting them into the space using `envfit()`, by passing it the NMDS object and the species data, `community_matrix` in your case. If you have a lot of species, I would probably dispense with the permutations, unless you really need such an indication of significance.

Comment: Thus significance of the projected vectors in NMDS is not reliable?

Comment: Well, they are reliable if the assumptions of the method are met, which are those of a linear model (in the sense of the general linear model). If the assumption of linearity is not appropriate for the data/NMDS solution to hand, then yes, the p-value would be as reliable as if you'd fitted a simple linear regression to data that clearly came from an underlying polynomial or non-linear function. The rank ordering may be consistent with a linear relationship, but it could just as well not be.

Comment: Hence we have `ordisurf()` which allows the assumption of linearity to be tested via a GAM surface fit rather than the linear plane assumed by the arrow fitting.