# for loop not populating data frame to plot ellipse in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I am working on a community ecology analysis, and have used the metaMDS function from the vegan package to create a set of points to plot. I tried following this previous example [Plotting ordiellipse function from vegan package onto NMDS plot created in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13794419/14251223)
However, in my case the for loop is not running correctly. These are my nmds scores:

```
gen_2019_site.scrs <- as.data.frame(scores(hel_gen_2019_nmds, display = "sites"))
gen_2019_site.scrs <- cbind(gen_2019_site.scrs, "Forest Coverage" = landscape_2019$Genera_2019_FQ)
gen_2019_site.scrs
```

| NMDS1 | NMDS2 | NMDS3 | Forest Coverage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.01239620 | -0.35564430 | -0.3568236724 | F3 |
| 0.36384679 | -0.18408880 | -0.0618107711 | F1 |
| -0.04411892 | 0.38898157 | 0.1333310873 | F5 |
| -0.30058417 | 0.03967635 | 0.0041468720 | F2 |
| 0.03221559 | -0.08918320 | 0.3013787345 | F2 |
| 0.12416181 | -0.16631897 | 0.1091838635 | F1 |
| -0.12732362 | 0.26747627 | -0.2164860869 | F1 |
| 0.02056514 | -0.25946756 | 0.2799632995 | F2 |
| 0.13859365 | 0.16943544 | -0.2485090677 | F3 |
| 0.18413252 | -0.13721912 | 0.1782989227 | F2 |
| -0.25055749 | 0.30259844 | 0.0008892452 | F4 |
| 0.39622215 | 0.34536077 | -0.0881237834 | F1 |
| 0.18078468 | -0.10871097 | 0.0972200679 | F1 |
| 0.28217778 | -0.09857696 | -0.3025316708 | F4 |
| -0.51108610 | -0.18696202 | -0.1046698976 | F2 |
| 0.19347030 | 0.09482813 | 0.1153315154 | F2 |
| 0.13955748 | 0.03051796 | 0.2791992925 | F2 |
| -0.56016509 | -0.05928792 | 0.1780053536 | F4 |
| -0.04069194 | 0.11660629 | -0.2203193485 | F3 |
| -0.05838748 | 0.20457427 | 0.0616040447 | F2 |
| 0.05138256 | 0.01433274 | 0.0466866895 | F2 |
| -0.20692179 | -0.39817145 | -0.1074178632 | F2 |
| -0.09968087 | 0.04533097 | -0.2597924682 | F5 |
| 0.19142410 | -0.24604250 | 0.0643757014 | F2 |
| -0.08662087 | 0.26995459 | 0.1168699402 | F5 |

and the code I tried based of the previous example was:

```
gen_2019_NMDS = data.frame(MDS1 = hel_gen_2019_nmds$points[,1], MDS2 = hel_gen_2019_nmds$points[,2],group=gen_2019_site.scrs$`Forest Coverage`)
gen_2019_NMDS.mean=aggregate(gen_2019_NMDS[,1:2],list(group=gen_2019_NMDS$group),mean)
veganCovEllipse<-function (cov, center = c(0, 0), scale = 1, npoints = 100) 
{
  theta <- (0:npoints) * 2 * pi/npoints
  Circle <- cbind(cos(theta), sin(theta))
  t(center + scale * t(Circle %*% chol(cov)))
}

df_ell.gen2019.forest <- data.frame()
for(g in levels(gen_2019_NMDS$group)){
  df_ell.gen2019.forest <- rbind(df_ell.gen2019.forest, cbind(as.data.frame(with(gen_2019_NMDS[gen_2019_NMDS$group==g,],
                           veganCovEllipse(cov.wt(cbind(MDS1,MDS2),wt=rep(1/length(MDS1),length(MDS1)))$cov,center=c(mean(MDS1),mean(MDS2))))) ,group=g))
}
```

but when I run the for loop to try and get the data for graphing the ellipses, it runs with no errors or warnings however it remains an object with 0 obs of 0 variables. Ideally I would like to plot 5 ellipses based on the Forest Coverage levels like so.

```
ggplot(gen_2019_site.scrs, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2))+ 
  geom_point(aes(NMDS1, NMDS2, colour = factor(`Forest Coverage`) ), size = 2)+ 
  geom_path(data=df_ell.gen2019.forest, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2,colour=group), size=1, linetype=2)
```

But currently there's no data to plot the geom_path code. Any suggestions of where I have made a misstep in the coding would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: +1 for giving your data as a html (although dput would've been better). What is `hel_gen_2019_nmds`. It is currently not reproducible because we lack this info. :-)

Comment: Hi Oliver, hel_gen_2019_nmds is the ordination output from a community matrix created using vegan's metaMDS function. The scores of each sample location to plot in ordination space are the scores shared in the data table here. Not sure how to share the information behind the hel_gen_2019_nmds object

Comment: I really don't know what is the trouble, as I did not find it. When I copy&pasted your commands (after renaming `Shrub` to `Forest Coverage` in `mite.env`), I got the results. which start: `> df_ell.gen2019.forest
            MDS1          MDS2 group
1    0.957945499 -0.0995403522  None
2    0.957315316 -0.0797844252  None
3    0.955427255 -0.0597318274  None` (but cannot be formatted in a comment, that's the first three lines). Perhaps you did something differently than you wrote in your message?

Comment: Further: like I said, copy&paste gave data `df_ell.gen2019.forest` for drawing ellipses, but  you command does not draw them: in `ggplot` and `geom_point` your `aes(NMDS1, NMDS2)` is correct, but you have different variable names in `geom_path` and you need `aes(MDS1, MDS2)` there.

Comment: For a "reproducible case" you do not need to give your data, but it is OK if you demonstrate the problem with generally available data. For instance, in your case I used the `mite` and `mite.env` data with renamed variables to track your problems. You should have done the same: check if you have the same problem with publically available data sets. If you can't reproduce the problem with standard data sets, you should search the problem somewhere else than in the functions.