# Adding a 95% confidence interval to NMDS plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix, plot, graph

I am trying to plot an NMDS plot of species community composition data with ellipses which represent 95% confidence intervals. I generated the data for my NMDS plot using metaMDS and successfully have ordinations generated using the basic plot functions in R (see code below). However, I am struggling to get my data to plot successfully using ggplot2 and this is the only way I have seen 95% CIs plotted on NMDS plots. I am hoping someone is able to help me correct my code so the ellipses show 95% CIs, or could point me in the right direction for achieving this using other methods?

My basic code for plotting my NMDS plot:

```
orditorp(dung.families.mds, display = "sites", labels = F, pch = c(16, 8, 17, 18) [as.numeric(group.variables$Heating)], col = c("green", "blue", "orange", "black") [as.numeric(group.variables$Dungfauna)], cex = 1.3)
ordiellipse(dung.families.mds, groups = group.variables$Dungfauna, draw = "polygon", lty = 1, col = "grey90")
legend("topleft", "stress = 0.1329627", bty = "n", cex = 1)
```

My ordination:
[image: NMDS ordination plot]

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old, but I found this post useful for plotting confidence ellipses during my work, and maybe it will help you. [Plotting ordiellipse function from vegan package onto NMDS plot created in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794419/plotting-ordiellipse-function-from-vegan-package-onto-nmds-plot-created-in-ggplo)

Edit: Below I have copied the code from the second part of Didzis Elferts's answer on the link above.
Where "sol" is the metaMDS object:

> First, make NMDS data frame with group column.

> ```
> NMDS = data.frame(MDS1 = sol$points[,1], MDS2 = >sol$points[,2],group=MyMeta$amt)
> ```

> Next, save result of function `ordiellipse()` as some object.

> ```
> ord<-ordiellipse(sol, MyMeta$amt, display = "sites", >kind = "se", conf = 0.95, label = T)
> ```

> Data frame `df_ell` contains values to show ellipses. It is calculated again with function `veganCovEllipse` which is hidden in `vegan` package. This function is applied to each level of NMDS (group) and now it uses arguments stored in `ord` object - `cov`, `center` and `scale` of each level.

```
df_ell <- data.frame()
for(g in levels(NMDS$group)){
  df_ell <- rbind(df_ell, cbind(as.data.frame(with(NMDS[NMDS$group==g,],
                  veganCovEllipse(ord[[g]]$cov,ord[[g]]$center,ord[[g]]$scale)))
                                ,group=g))
}
```

> Plotting is done the same way as in previous example. As for the calculating of coordinates for elipses object of `ordiellipse()` is used, this solution will work with different parameters you provide for this function.

```
ggplot(data = NMDS, aes(MDS1, MDS2)) + geom_point(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_path(data=df_ell, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2,colour=group), size=1, linetype=2)
```